# Getting specific data from JSON Model

Tags: c#, json, model

Here is my JSON model for trying to get info from Google Maps API.  I am trying to get the "name" and "vicinity" from the "Result "class, but am having trouble with getting the data values from the IList, preferably i would like all the name and vicinity attributes to be returned as a string.  Anyone got any ideas?  Not familiar with using IList's on projects.

```
public record Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public record Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public record Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public record Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public record Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public record OpeningHours
    {
        public bool? open_now { get; set; }
    }

    public record Photo
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public IList<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string photo_reference { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public record PlusCode
    {
        public string compound_code { get; set; }
        public string global_code { get; set; }
    }

    public record Result
    {
        public string business_status { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string icon_background_color { get; set; }
        public string icon_mask_base_uri { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
        public IList<Photo> photos { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public PlusCode plus_code { get; set; }
        public double rating { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public IList<string> types { get; set; }
        public int user_ratings_total { get; set; }
        public string vicinity { get; set; }
    }

    public record ResourceData
    {
        public IList<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public IList<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public record record_GooglePlacesAPI
    {
        public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public ResourceData resourceData { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running a simple LINQ query on the data returned from google API like the following

```
        //string holding google api response
        string googleResponse = string.Empty;

        var googleapi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<record_GooglePlacesAPI>(googleResponse);

        //Linq query that returns list of names and vicinities
        List<string> vicinities = googleapi.resourceData.results.Select(r => r.vicinity).ToList();
        List<string> names = googleapi.resourceData.results.Select(r => r.name).ToList();
```

it should return you a list of strings holding names and viciniteis